# Is there a way to test Angular Router with Jest?

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs, angular-router

I'm trying to test if an element in a sidebar is correctly collapsed when a user navigates to a page. I'm having troubles trying to mock the Angular Router in my Jest tests.

The code i'm trying to test:

```
this.router.events.pipe(
            filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        ).subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
            this.current = event.url;
            if (this.current.includes('page1')) {
                this._expandMenu(this.page1Toggle);

                if (this.current.includes('page2')) {
                    this._expandMenu(this.page2Toggle);
                }
            }
            this._closeMenu();
        });
```

Trying to mock the router:

```
let eventSubject: Subject<Event> = new Subject<Event>();

export class MockRouter {
    events: Observable<Event> = eventSubject;
}
```

The test:

```
it('should open page1 dropdown if on page1', fakeAsync(() => {
        // Arrange
        let event = new NavigationEnd(1, '/home/page1', '');

        // Act
        eventSubject.next(event);
        flush();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        let page1Toggle = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#page1Toggle'));
        let dropdown = page1Toggle.nativeElement.nextSibling;

        // Assert
        expect(page1Toggle.attributes['aria-expanded']).toBeTruthy();
        expect(dropdown.classList).toContain('show');
    }));
```

I've tried providing the Router as such `{ provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter}`
but keep getting errors when trying to instantiate the fixture:

```
let fixture: ComponentFixture<SideBarComponent>;
let comp: SideBarComponent;
beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                SideBarComponent,
            ],
            imports: [
                RouterTestingModule
            ],
            providers: [
                { provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter}
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SideBarComponent); --Cannot read property 'root' of undefined
comp = fixture.componentInstance;
```

Comment: Worth noting that i'm doing this with Angular 8 and Jest 24.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a better way to handle the show/collapse functionality by used Angular's [RouterLinkActive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive)